# How to read a tab delimited file into Python with rows of unequal length?

Tags: python, numpy, text-files, csv

I have a text file which is the results of measurements. When the object is not in the correct place to be measured it cannot take the full suite of measurements, which gives rows of unequal length in the text file.

How can this be read in Python? Do I have to fill in the spaces in the text file with blanks?

What the data looks like:

[image: what the data looks like]

Code I tried:

```
from numpy import loadtxt
lines = loadtxt(file_to_read, comments="#", delimiter="\t", unpack=False)
```

But it gave an error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Height\tLength\tVolume\tSpeed\tWeight'
```

Then I tried:

```
file_to_read = ('/Users/path/to/file//dummy_data.txt')
file_object = open(file_to_read, 'r')
file_object.read()
print(file_object)
```

But it returned nothing, I like to see the data to see if it has the correct format.

Comment: Did you try adding `skiprows=1` to your call to `loadtxt`? (also, the delimiter is `\t`, not `/t`

Comment: The rows are probably not unequal length, they will just have empty fields.

Comment: thanks GPhilo, I shall edit the question for the tab deli format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also works easily with pandas, keeping the header as columns:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(file_to_read, sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that you are trying to import the header row. Use the `skiprows` parameter to `loadtxt` to skip this row:

```
lines = loadtxt(file_to_read, comments="#", delimiter="\t", skiprows=1, unpack=False)
```

You can read more about the `loadtxt` function in [the manual](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

Comment: The delimiter should be `"\t"`.

Answer (score 2):

Using pandas should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\t').to_numpy()
```

output:

```
array([[1. , 0.5, 0.2],
       [0.1, nan, nan],
       [nan, 0.1, 5. ]])
```

Where `data.csv` contains:

```
A   B   C
1   .5  .2
.1      
    .1  5
```

Comment: Thank you Simon, I had just added the library after wabu's suggestion as it was not in my vs code already strangely. It works with pandas as you suggest.